# How to reassign monitor numbers in Windows 10

Tags: windows, display

I have two monitors, Windows 10 identifies them as 1 and 2. I'd like to change which one is which. Is it possible?

Please do not reply that I should go to display settings and drag monitors around to represent my physical layout, or that I should mark the desired monitor as primary. I have done all that already. It fixes ALMOST all issues, but e.g. every time I restart my laptop and open Visual Studio, it opens on monitor #1, though I marked #2 as primary.

Answer (score 7):

Next to impossible to change those numbers around.
The only method that might get you somewhere involves playing with your cables.

First, back up your registry so you can roll things back if it breaks.

Then delete these registry keys:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Systems\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Systems\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Connectivity

Power off your PC and unplug all your monitor cables from the back of it.

Power it back up with just one monitor connected then add the rest one at a time.

Downsides: If you have a laptop and want the built in screen to be something other than 1, then you are out of luck.
And it may not work at all. Sometimes the number gets allocated if the hardware reports itself as active. My graphics card has a composite port which grabs a number even if unconnected. My setup has three screens numbered 1, 3 and 4 because of it.

Comment: Thanks @Buzby. I suspected something like this. My laptop is connected to the two monitors via a USB dock. Do you think the two numbers get assigned as soon as I connect the dock, whether the monitors are connected to it or not?

Comment: Depends on the hardware. It might wait until you connect a monitor and assign it the next number. It might assign both ports even if nothing is plugged in. It might even have a built in numbering system (which we can't see from the outside its graphics processor) that will allocate both ports the next two numbers in the same order no matter which port is connected first. There are no guarantee with monitor numbering.

Comment: This did not work on Windows 11 and latest Nvidia driver.